# ReactJS Updating Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently starting to learn ReactJS and have run into some trouble updating an array.

Currently I have a searchable list of contacts which is working fine. But using the input box below the list I am trying to add additional items to the list using the update() function.

Sample of what I've got so far for the update function is below. Ideally at some point the updated content would come from the input box to the left of the button, but currently I'm just trying to push a static item as a test.

```
  updateContact: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newItems = React.addons.update(this.state.initialItems, {$push: ["New Item"]})
    return;
  },
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, and a full JSFiddle with the entire code can be found below.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30nfdbag/2/)

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? Does something not work as expected? What is it and what do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling [**`setState`**](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), so the component never re-renders:

```
updateContact: function(e){
  e.preventDefault():
  var newItems = React.addons.update(this.state.initialItems, {$push: ["New Item"]});

  this.setState({
    initialItems: newItems,
    items: newItems
  }); // update state
},
```

Note that update both, `this.state.items`,  `this.state.initialItems`. I assume you are using `items` for the filtered list and `initialItems` for all items in the list.

Of course you have to replace `"New Item"` with the actual value of the text field.

---

I would also remove `componentWillMount` and simply set `initialItems` and `items` to the same value in `getInitialState`.

Also if you'd simply bind the handler directly to the button and remove the `<form>`, you don't have to deal with preventing the event. It seems a rather roundabout way to trigger the callback.

Cleaned up example: https://jsfiddle.net/f554xrh0/

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I was missing something as simple as just updating the state. As for the initialItems vs items, I had followed a tutorial to set that part up and wasn't sure either, I appreciate the guidance on that too.